# Yodify: English to Yoda English Conversion in Java

Tags: java

I'm developing a program which will convert natural english into Yoda style of english in Star Wars. A single sentence conversion looks fine but I'm having problems when it comes to multiple sentences. Here is my code.

```
public class Yodify{
    public static void main(String[] args){

       String sentence = "i like dogs. i like cats.";
       String[] paragraph = sentence.split("\\.");

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

       for (int i = 0; i < paragraph.length; i++){
           String[] temp = paragraph[i].split(" ");
               for (int x = 2; x < temp.length; x++){
                   sb.append([temp[x]).append(" ");
               }
           sb2.append(sb).append(temp[0]).append(" ").append(temp[1]).append(". ");
}
    System.out.println(sb2.toString);
}

}
```

My output:

> the dogs i like. the dogs the cats i like.

Expected output:

> the dogs i like. the cats i like.

I've been debugging this for hours also, I can't find what I need @ googling my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately your general problem appears to be much more complicated than the logic you have.  You are trying to change the word order of an English sentence.  This means you will need to have some AI for detecting the subject, verb, and predicate in _every_ sentence, not just the simple ones you have in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code is this line:

```
for (int x = 2; x < temp.length; x++){
    sb.append([temp[x]).append(" "); <--------------
```

This will append the third word of each sentence to a stringbuilder that isn't cleared after each loop. So the content of `sb` looks like this for your example-output before entering the loop:

```
sb             i              paragraph
""             0              i like dogs
"dogs"         1              i like cats
```

A simple fix for this would be to directly append to `sb2` in the for-loop intead of `sb`:

```
for (int x = 2; x < temp.length; x++){
    sb2.append([temp[x]).append(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you tried to implement a super-simple algorithm:
move the last word to the beginning of the sentence.
In reality, there's a bit more to Yoda-speak than that.

Correcting compilation errors and other issues in your program,
with a few added improvements, the implementation becomes:

```
    String sentence = "i like dogs. i like cats.";
    String[] paragraph = sentence.split("\\. *");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < paragraph.length; i++) {
        String[] temp = paragraph[i].split(" ");
        builder.append(temp[temp.length - 1]);
        for (int x = 0; x < temp.length - 1; x++){
            builder.append(" ").append(temp[x]);
        }
        builder.append(". ");
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```